Spring-Jms DefaultMessageListenerContainer ADT payloads Issue
I am working on a Springboot (1.5.14.RELEASE) and I upgraded that to Springboot 3.3.2.
I have an oracleAQ queue and I was using XmlMessageListenerContainer (Because my payloadtype is "SYS"."XMLTYPE" in queue table) from  org.springframework.data:spring-data-oracle:1.2.1.RELEASE with old version but now I need to use
DefaultMessageListenerContainer  from org.springframework:spring-jms:6.1.11, because there is no XML listener in the package.
When I run the project with new implementation I get an error
o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'XYZ.APPOINTMENT_QUEUE' - trying to recover. Cause: JMS-137: Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT payloads
I tried to add specification like below, but it didn't work
     OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) dataSource.getConnection();
     Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = oracleConnection.getTypeMap();
     typeMap.put("SYS.XMLTYPE", Class.forName("oracle.xdb.XMLTypeFactory"));

Here is my old implementation
 org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle

 @Bean( destroyMethod = "destroy" )
  public XmlMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer( final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      final CustomDatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration,
      final DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager,
      final OMessageListener oMessageListener,
      final XmlMessageConverter xmlMessageConverter )
  {
    final XmlMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new XmlMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory( connectionFactory );
    listenerContainer.setDestinationName( "XYZ.APPOINTMENT_QUEUE" );
    listenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers( databaseConfiguration.getMaximumPoolSize() );
    listenerContainer.setMessageConverter( xmlMessageConverter );
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener( oMessageListener );
    listenerContainer.setSessionAcknowledgeMode( Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED );
    listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted( true );
    listenerContainer.setTransactionManager( dataSourceTransactionManager );
    return listenerContainer;
  }

Here is my new implementation
  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
  public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                           final OracleDataSourceConfiguration.CustomDatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration,
                                                           final DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager,
                                                           final OMessageListener oMessageListener
                                                            ) {
    final DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    listenerContainer.setDestinationName("XYZ.APPOINTMENT_QUEUE");
    listenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(databaseConfiguration.getMaximumPoolSize());
 
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(oMessageListener);
    listenerContainer.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
    listenerContainer.setTransactionManager(dataSourceTransactionManager);

    return listenerContainer;
  }

